# Tracking KEY_ENTER in Ncurses

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, curses

How does one track `KEY_ENTER` in ncurses?  I have tried tracking `\n` using `getch()`, `KEY_ENTER`, and `raw()`, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like to use those key abbreviations like KEY_ENTER, you have to make a call to:

```
keypad(win, true);
```

before using them. Take a look at this: http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/man/html.CURSES/keypad.CURSES.html

Comment: Thanks.  Also, for *NIX systems, checking for '\n' seems to work.